# Occlusion of faces and edges with ViewMatrix

Tags: graphics3d, lighting

The code below should produce a red cube behind a green cube, in turn behind a blue cube. I intend the matrices `tmat` and `pmat` to produce a perspective projection from a viewpoint slightly to the left of the midpoint of the left-hand edge of the frame, and I think 8 times as far away from the screen as the frame is wide.

I have deliberately listed the cubes not in the order of their respective depths, in order to demonstrate that they do not seem to occlude each other correctly, unless I first sort them according to their depths.

Questions:

1) Why is the occlusion incorrect, and how can I fix this ? I seem to have to rely on the "Painter's Algorithm", i.e. drawing nearer objects AFTER further objects, which is well known not to give correct results in general, since objects need not be totally ordered by depth. Other experiments I have done with more objects lead me to believe that it is not a simple problem with surface normals caused by some confusion between left- and right-handed coordinate systems, but perhaps I am wrong about that.

2) Is there a way to draw the edges of the cubes, without also drawing the edges that should be hidden ? I have tried removing the command `EdgeForm[None]`, and using all 27 combinations of $a, b \in \{0, 0.5, 1\}$ with `FaceForm[{cubedatum[[2]],Opacity[a]}, {cubedatum[[2]], Opacity[b]}]` instead of `FaceForm[cubedatum[[2]],None]`, with `Lighting->{{"Directional",White,{{0,0,1},{0,0,0}}}}`, `Lighting->"Ambient"`, and `Lighting->"Neutral"`, but nothing worked.

I apologise for asking two questions at a time, but I suspect that their answers will be closely related.

```
tmat = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1, 160/33}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
pmat = {{8, 0, 13/40, 0}, {0, 8, -1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 
    8}};
cubeside = 1/8;
gap = 1/20;
cubecentrexs = {0, -gap, gap};
cubecentreys = 2 {0, -gap, gap};
cubecentrezs = {0, -gap, gap};
cubecentres = Transpose[{cubecentrexs, cubecentreys, cubecentrezs}];
cubecolours = {Green, Red, Blue};
(* Don't sort the cubes: *)    
cubedata = Transpose[{cubecentres, cubecolours}];
cubes = Table[{FaceForm[cubedatum[[2]], None], EdgeForm[None], 
    Cuboid[cubedatum[[1]] - (cubeside/2) {1, 1, 1}, 
     cubedatum[[1]] + (cubeside/2) {1, 1, 1}]}, {cubedatum, cubedata}];
picwithoutsorting = 
 Graphics3D[cubes, ViewMatrix -> {tmat, pmat}, Boxed -> False, 
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}}}]
(* Sort the cubes by their z-coordinate: *)    
cubedata = 
  Sort[Transpose[{cubecentres, 
     cubecolours}], #1[[1, 3]] <= #2[[1, 3]] &];
cubes = Table[{FaceForm[cubedatum[[2]], None], EdgeForm[None], 
    Cuboid[cubedatum[[1]] - (cubeside/2) {1, 1, 1}, 
     cubedatum[[1]] + (cubeside/2) {1, 1, 1}]}, {cubedatum, cubedata}];
picwithsorting = 
 Graphics3D[cubes, ViewMatrix -> {tmat, pmat}, Boxed -> False, 
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}}}]
```

Output:

This is `picwithoutsorting`:

[image: picwithoutsorting]

And this is `picwithsorting`:

[image: picwithsorting]